# IntelliJ TypeScript barrel file: Way to jump to the original file with Ctrl + click?

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea, webstorm

I have some barrel files in my project to improve bundling. One annoyance is that I must jump through the barrel file to reach the original file with <kbd>Ctrl + Click</kbd>.

Is there a way or a plugin to get me directly to the original file?

Comment: Just a thought... `Ctrl+Click` should be bound to "Go to Declaration or Usages" action (`Ctrl+B` here on Windows). Which I believe behaves correctly in your case -- it jumps where that import is declared (to you barrel file). Try "Go to Type Declaration" instead (`Ctrl+Shift+B` / `Ctrl+Shift+Click` here) -- any better?

Comment: This does the exact same thing for me. If it helps, this is an example export from my barrel file:
`export const Link = dynamic(() => import(/* webpackChunkName: "CoreFeaturesEager" */ '@/core/features/link/link'));`

Comment: In such a case I may only suggest to contact JetBrains WebStorm Support -- in your IDE just use `Help | Contact Support` to create a support ticket.