# Can I get WebStorm to skip files that are single lines with export statements when navigating?

Tags: webstorm

I'm looking for the site banner, so I tap [Shift Shift](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2020/05/when-the-shift-hits-the-fan-search-everywhere/) and search for "sitebanner", which leads me to `packages/shared/src/app/components/index.ts`. I open that and it is one line:

```
export { default as SiteBanner } from './SiteBanner';
```

I Cmd + click on `'./SiteBanner';` which leads me to:

```
export { default } from './SiteBanner';
```

I Cmd + click on *that* `./SiteBanner` and it leads me to the right place.

We have roughly 150 files like this in our code base. It's a pattern the org has adopted. It's usually just one (like the second one).

Is there any way to tell WebStorm to just skip files that only have one line and that line is an export? Kind of like how Java tools will skip/collapse empty directories.

Comment: What is shift-shift?

Comment: @Barmar *"What is shift-shift?"* WebStorm's Search Everywhere (classes/files/symbols/settings/actions -- all at once) -- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/searching-everywhere.html#search_all

Comment: I've been using PhpStorm for several years, I never discovered that shortcut.

Comment: I guess you can try and add new File Watcher maybe.

Comment: I usually use Find In Files (Cmd-Shift-F), it allows you to define scopes to search. But I don't see any way to exclude 1-line files in a scope.

Comment: I guess it's very similar (if not the same) situation as in https://stackoverflow.com/q/74776913/783119 (TypeScript's barrel files).